# Node.js and express requiring routes from separate files only working for index routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

How to require/link routes from separate files? I am using express router in the routes files then requiring the files in my app.js, but only the /home and /privacy-policy routes are working

app.js:

```
const express        = require("express"),
      app            = express();

const indexRoutes    = require("./routes/index");
      checkoutRoutes = require("./routes/checkout"); 

app.use("/", indexRoutes);
app.use("/checkout", checkoutRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server Started"));
```

/routes/index.js:

```
const express = require("express"),
      router  = express.Router();

const checkoutRoutes = require("./checkout");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/home");
});

router.get("/home", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

router.get("/privacy-policy", (req, res) => {
    res.render("privacyPolicy")
});

module.exports = router;
```

/routes/checkout.js:

```
const express = require("express"),
      router  = express.Router();

router.get("/checkout", (req, res) => {
    res.render("checkout");
});

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Define "working". What happens if you try to hit another route?

Comment: when I go to /home or /privacy-policy the files are rendered and everything works like expected, but when I visit /checkout I get Cannot GET /checkout

Answer (score 1):

Your router handles `/checkout` and you are mounting it at `/checkout` which makes the full path to the route `/checkout/checkout`.

You probably want the route in *checkout.js* to be `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Your checkout.js file should look like this, if you want have `GET /checkout`

```
const express = require("express"),
      router  = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("checkout");
});

module.exports = router
```